# What happens to up/down votes when not logged in?

Tags: support, voting, post-feedback, anonymous-visitors

If I don't have an account on a particular StackExchange site and I attempt to up/down vote a question or answer I receive this message

> Thanks for the feedback!
>
> This site is free and open to everyone, but our registered users get extra privileges like posting, commenting, and voting.

and the vote apparently doesn't go through, which is fine.

**Is anything done with these clicks that affects the site?  That affects anything?**

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/220020/qa-anon-feedback - toss a question id in there on the appropriate site and see what you get back. I've used it today to decide if something should be flagged for deletion or historical lock.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not a whole lot, at least right now.

- They feed into some analytics that mods & employees use to keep an eye on the general health of the sites.
- They're put into the public data dumps and [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for perusal by all and sundry.
- They influence the selection of [Greatest Hits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits).

There *were* some 10K tools as well (now hidden) intended to help flush out posts that were getting exceptional amounts of anonymous feedback; we may bring these back in some form eventually.

Comment: Any chance for this to affect hotness score, as partially suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238514/users-arriving-at-a-bad-hot-network-question-should-be-able-to-express-their-dis)?

Comment: Huh. That seems really rude. I've upvoted lots of things when not logged in, and assumed "Thanks for the feedback" meant, well, that the vote counted for something.